# C - Macro detects wrong datatypes

Tags: c, types, char, constants, overloading

I'm trying to define a macro that prints any datatype correctly but it appears to detect what type I'm passing incorrectly. Why?

Code: (I've left out the includes but they're there.)

```c
void print_int(int x) { printf("PRINTING INT: %d", x); }
void print_float(float x) { printf("%.3f", x); }
void print_char(char x) { printf("%c", x); }
void print_string(char *x) { printf("%s", x); }
void print_bool(bool x) { printf("%s", x ? "true" : "false"); }

#define print(X) \
    _Generic((X),\
        int: print_int, \
        float: print_float, \
        double: print_float, \
        char: print_char, \
        char *: print_string, \
        bool: print_bool)(X)

int main(void) {
    
    printf("\n\nprint string: ");
    print("Hello there!"); // prints as string

    printf("\nprint int: ");
    print(3); // prints as int

    printf("\nprint float: ");
    print(4.55); // prints as float

    printf("\nprint bool: ");
    print(false); // prints as bool

    printf("\nprint char: ");
    print('A'); // prints as char

    return 0;
}
```

Actual output:

```
print string: Hello there!
print int: PRINTING INT: 3
print float: 4.550
print bool: PRINTING INT: 0
print char: PRINTING INT: 65
```

Correct output:

```
print string: Hello there!
print int: PRINTING INT: 3
print float: 4.550
print bool: false
print char: A
```

I'd love to know where this is going wrong, because I have no clue.

Comment: `false` and `'A'` have the type `int`, so the output is correct.

Comment: Then how would I work around that?

Comment: Add casting: `print((bool)false);`
   `print((char)'A');` But I guess it is defeating what you are trying to do (which we can only guess though)

Comment: Is there a way to i.e. put that in the macro rather than the call itself? I'm trying to avoid casting and stuff.

Comment: If you want polymorphism - learm C++. C workarounds are hard to write and read + they are error prone.

Comment: No. From the compiler perspective `'A'` is the same as `65`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this call

```
print('A');
```

the argument is an integer character constant.

Integer character constants in C (opposite to C++ where they are named character literals) have the type `int` instead of the type `char`.

From the C Standard (6.4.4.4 Character constants)

> 10 **An integer character constant has type int**.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows this peculiarity of C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "suzeof( 'A' ) = %zu\n", sizeof( 'A' ) );
    
    char c = 'A';
    
    printf( "suzeof( c ) = %zu\n", sizeof( c ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
suzeof( 'A' ) = 4
suzeof( c ) = 1
```

If you want to get the expected by you result then write

```
print( (char )'A' );
```

or

```
char c = 'A';
print( c );
```

Comment: @SjoerdVermeulen You can at first assign the integer character constant to an object of the type char and then use this object as an argument of the function call.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: @SjoerdVermeulen learn C++ if you need polymorphism. That is the best solution :)

Comment: This question is similar to a C-only problem on a code challenge website. I'm not saying that's why the poster is asking, but let's not necessarily assume that it's a case of someone not knowing how to choose the right language for their needs.

Comment: Don't worry, I know my languages and when to use which one all right. I just want to use c for this bc of preference reasons that have little to do with wether c is the perfect language for this case or not.